# api response unreadable

Tags: java, android

I am getting an unreadable format of data when I called the api in android. But my actual response via postman as follows.

[image: postman response]

When I debug the code response is as follows.

[image: api response after debugged the android app]

Why the data response is showing like so? How can I get the data as in postman response?

Comment: It would help if you could show us the class you're trying to deserialize into.

Comment: which framework are you using to run this request, and which json parser is registered to it?

Answer (score 0):

You need right click data and select inspection  .. Then click view text